# How to prevent VSCode opening output panel after each save?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My VSCode recently (within the last 2 weeks, so I am assuming there was some change in the last VSCode release) started opening the Output panel each time I save a file. If the panel is already open with another view (e.g., Terminal), the focus switches to the Output panel.

The Output panel gets opened because I have enabled these settings:

```py
    "python.workspaceSymbols.rebuildOnFileSave": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
```

Hence, the corresponding output is shown in the Output panel.

If I set those settings to `false`, the Output panel does not open after the save.

However, I have had those exact settings for months and no other relevant changes in my config and never had the problem that the Output panel opens after each saves. And I would like to have the settings as given above.

Question: How can I prevent the Output panel from opening after each saves? Or prevent it from opening altogether?

I haven't found a setting to do this. And I'm surprised that no other users seem to have this issue.

Comment: FYI, if anybody happens to have the same problem: As a workaround until this is fixed I bind a key to workbench.action.togglePanel so at least I can close the panel immediately after each open.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger is that `"python.workspaceSymbols.rebuildOnFileSave": true` was not implemented until the latest release. As for why the Output Panel is opening, I'm not sure. If you could open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python then hopefully we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, Brett, will do.

Comment: FYI, here's the link to the issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9603